# MIPS assembly function take user input and read as array?

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi all I am trying to write a program in MIPs to convert Hexadecimal to Binary

My current idea was to read hexa value of each position, and convert into 4 bit binary string respectively and concatenate together into a array

For instance if i get a user input of 3CFF03D8, they i would like to first access the value of first position, which is 3, and convert it to binary in 0011,

then access the value of second position, which is C, and convert it to binary and so forth.

I am able to query user input just fine, I tried 
say $s0 is where I stored the user input, trying to treat it like an array.

sw $t0, 0($s0) #t0 = s0[0]

but obviously it wasn't simple and didn't work

Comment: A hex digit is 4 bits (a nibble).  A single byte (`lbu`) contains 2 nibbles.  e.g. the value of the lowest byte of `0x3CFF03D8` is `0xD8`, if you're storing it as an integer in a little-endian MIPS system like MARS/SPIM.  Or is your user input a string of ASCII characters in memory?

Comment: oh do you reckon it will work if i store user input as a ascii character based string?